# Loading FITS images with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, astropy, fits

I'm trying to create a CNN using PyTorch but my images need importing from the FITS format rather than conventional .png or .jpeg etc.

Is there a way to accomplish this easily using torch.utils.data.DataLoader or is there a place in the source code where I can put in a clause which will handle FITS files while loading in?

I have looked in the documentation and the most relevant thing I've found is the ToPILImage transformer which converts a tensor or ndarray into a PIL Image.

Currently I'm using an image loading routine as follows:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision

batch_size = 4

transform = transforms.Compose(
                   [transforms.Resize((32,32)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    ])

trainset = dset.ImageFolder(root="Documents/Image_data",transform=transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
```

Astropy: http://www.astropy.org/

Pytorch: https://pytorch.org/

torch.utils: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html

UPDATE: Perhaps using torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder instead of DataLoader, an inserting in my own FITS handler would work?

When trying to use this class I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torchvision.datasets' has no attribute 'DatasetFolder'
```

Is DatasetFolder actually supported by torchvision at this point in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading some combination of the docs and the code, I don't think you necessarily want to be using `ImageFolder` since it doesn't know anything about FITS.

Instead you should try using the more generic [`DataSetFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html?highlight=imagefolder#datasetfolder) class (which in fact is the parent class of `ImageFolder`).  You would pass it a list of extensions it should handle (i.e. `['.fits']` and a "loader" function that takes a FITS file and, it seems, should return a `PIL.Image`.

You could even make your own subclass following the example of [`ImageFolder`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L150).  E.g.

```
class FitsFolder(DatasetFolder):

    EXTENSIONS = ['.fits']

    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, target_transform=None,
                 loader=None):
        if loader is None:
            loader = self.__fits_loader

        super(FitsFolder, self).__init__(root, loader, self.EXTENSIONS,
                                         transform=transform,
                                         target_transform=target_transform)

    @staticmethod
    def __fits_loader(filename):
        data = fits.getdata(filename)
        return Image.fromarray(data)
```

The exact details of `__fits_loader` may depend on the details of your FITS files.  This basic example just uses the high-level `fits.getdata()` function which returns the first image array in the FITS file (some FITS files may have many extensions with many images, or have tables etc.).  So that part would be up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks like a good way to do it for sure. However when trying to implement this idea I get the following error: module 'torchvision.datasets' has no attribute 'DatasetFolder'.

Comment: In fact, it looks like this was only added quite recently: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/444  So if you can't use the newest version of the package, you might have to reinvent the wheel a bit, unfortunately, but it would probably still mostly look the same (for example, you could subclass `ImageFolder`, though you'd have to reimplement a bit more of the `__init__` method).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I guess if I just copied the source code locally: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/folder.py
Then I could just call DatasetFolder and implement your method above? That'd be simpler.

Comment: You could do that as a temporary measure, sure.  Perhaps with a reminder that it can be removed upon upgrade to a future version of PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a FITS image to any format supported by [pyplot.imsave()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) using this method:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_data = fits.getdata(r"/path/to/image.fits")
plt.imsave("/path/to/image.png", image_data, cmap="gray")
```

Comment: A nice idea, unfortunately I need to keep the data in FITS format when archived so that I can use it quickly and easily in Astronomical pipelines.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. This answer demonstrates loading the data from the FITS file, and then writing it out to a separate ".png" file.  You wouldn't lose the FITS data at all.  Otherwise, I'm not familiar with PyTorch but maybe there is a way for it to be extended to read FITS files.

Comment: Apologies, my point was that rather than converting the FITS into a png and saving the images for loading into PyTorch, I am more focused on reading in a FITS directly into PyTorch without the need for a middle stage which duplicates the images into png format -as I believe your recent answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem as @user8188120 a few weeks ago. Using @Iguananaut's answer works great when reading labels from the folder structure. If someone stumbles upon this and needs reading from csv file, this might also work:

```
labels = []
transform = transforms.Compose([
    # here go your transforms
    ])


class MyFitsDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        # Read the csv file
        self.data_info = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
        # First column contains the image paths
        self.image_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 0])
        # the rest contain the labels
        self.label_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 1:])  # for multi-label
        self.label_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 1])  # for single-label
        labels.append(self.label_arr)
        self.data_len = len(self.data_info.index)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        single_image_name = self.image_arr[index]

        data = pyfits.open(single_image_name, axes=2)
        data = data[0].data.astype('float32')
        data = data.reshape(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, CHANNELS)

        img = transform(data)

        # Get label(class) of the image based on the pandas column
        single_image_label = self.label_arr[index]

        return (img, single_image_label)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_len
```

This also avoids using the `DatasetFolder` class, which still isn't available in the newest version of PyTorch. I hope this helps someone.